# How to loop an Update statement so that it updates all possible unique combinations?

Tags: mysql

I have an `update` statement that updates a table with a concatenated name generated from a random combination of three other tables (First, Middle, and Last) to create a random full name. I use `alter table Full add unique index(full);` to ensure that no name is used twice, and any time it would use a name that is already in use it instead makes it null.

The tables I am using give me a possible 27 unique names. I want to figure out how to loop my update statement so that it fills in every possible unique combination.

db-fiddle table

```
create table First (id int(10), first varchar(255));
Insert into First (id, first) values (1, 'John'), (2, 'Bill'), (3, 'Chad');
create table Middle (id int(10), middle varchar(255));
Insert into Middle (id, middle) values (1, 'Ethan'), (2, 'Dave'), (3, 'Ron');                                                
create table Last (id int(10), last varchar(255));
Insert into Last (id, last) values (1, 'Smith'), (2, 'Miller'), (3, 'Darnold');
create table Full (id int(10) auto_increment primary key, full varchar(255)); 
insert into Full (id) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30);
```

This is my current `Update` statement

```
alter table Full add unique index(full);
Update ignore Full u1
join (select id,
             @i:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             @j:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             @k:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
             (select concat(l.last, ', ', f.first, ' ', m.middle) 
              from First as f 
              join Middle as m on m.id = @j 
              join Last as l on l.id = @k
              where f.id = @i) full 
      from Full) u2
on u1.id = u2.id
set u1.full = u2.full;
```

I can't loop it as is because it generates a full list of names every time. I need to change it so that after the first run it only updates null names if any possible combinations are left. I have experimented with inserting it into a case statement, but I can't get it to work correctly. As it is, it just changes one of the names in the table to 1, so its obviously not working as intended.

```
Update ignore Full
join (  select id,
        @i:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
        @j:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
        @k:=Floor(1+ RAND() * 3),
        (   select concat(l.last, ', ', f.first, ' ', m.middle) 
            from First as f 
            join Middle as m on m.id = @j 
            join Last as l on l.id = @k
            where f.id = @i) full
        From Full) u2
Set u1.full = Case 
            when u1.full is null 
            then u1.full = u2.full
            else u1.full = u1.full
            end;
```

If it was working as intended it would fill the all the null rows except 3, since that is all the unique combinations that are possible given my small table size. I want to make sure it's working as intended before I scale up the tables.

Edit:
I don't actually NEED every possible combination. In my actual table I do need every null row filled with a unique combination, and as it is now when a name is duplicated it is `null`. So I need to fill those while also not duplicating a name already in the table.

Edit2:
I have changed it to this

```
Update ignore Full f1
join (select id, 
                     (SELECT concat(last, ', ', first, ' ', middle) fullname FROM First,Middle,Last ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) fullname
from Full ) f2
on f1.id = f2.id
set f1.full = f2.fullname;
```

Which works. Now I just need it to loop until there are no `null` rows left.

Comment: If you want every combination, then what's the point of RAND?

Comment: I wont actually use every possible combination once it is scaled up. I figured it made sense to do it this way so that I know its working correctly before I scale it up to my actual tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
SELECT first, middle, last FROM first,middle,last ORDER BY RAND();
+-------+--------+---------+
| first | middle | last    |
+-------+--------+---------+
| Bill  | Ethan  | Smith   |
| John  | Dave   | Miller  |
| Bill  | Ron    | Darnold |
| Bill  | Ethan  | Darnold |
| John  | Ethan  | Miller  |
| Chad  | Ethan  | Darnold |
| Chad  | Ethan  | Smith   |
| Bill  | Ron    | Miller  |
| John  | Dave   | Darnold |
| Chad  | Dave   | Miller  |
| Chad  | Ron    | Miller  |
| John  | Ethan  | Darnold |
| Chad  | Dave   | Smith   |
| Bill  | Ron    | Smith   |
| John  | Dave   | Smith   |
| Bill  | Ethan  | Miller  |
| John  | Ron    | Smith   |
| John  | Ethan  | Smith   |
| Bill  | Dave   | Smith   |
| Chad  | Dave   | Darnold |
| Chad  | Ethan  | Miller  |
| John  | Ron    | Miller  |
| Chad  | Ron    | Darnold |
| John  | Ron    | Darnold |
| Bill  | Dave   | Darnold |
| Bill  | Dave   | Miller  |
| Chad  | Ron    | Smith   |
+-------+--------+---------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That seems so much easier than what I was trying. Let me see if I can put something together to use that to update my table and I'll post my results.

Comment: I came up with this ```Update ignore Full f1
join (select id, 
      (SELECT concat(last, ', ', first, ' ', middle) fullname FROM First,Middle,Last ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) fullname
from Full ) f2
on f1.id = f2.id
set f1.full = f2.fullname;``` which works. I still would like to loop it, but I could run it manually until all the null rows as filled as well.

Comment: So while this works, it takes entirely too long. To update a table with 30 rows takes almost a minute. There is no way I can use this as is to update my large tables. Some tweaking will definitely be needed.

Comment: A table with 30 rows is going to have a minimum of 3 duplicates, right?

Comment: Not if I use ```alter table Full add unique index(full);``` and tell it to ```ignore``` then it would have 27 unique and 3 null rows.

Comment: And that's what you would like to have?